# I can't change background color another activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have two activity. **Cores** and **MudaCor**. In **Cores** i have four buttons, selecting anything here tries to changes button color from **MudaCor** and start it, but the Android Emulator tell me *"Error on App."*

```
public class MudaCor extends AppCompatActivity { 
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_muda_cor); 
    } 
}
```

---

```
    btnVermelho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            img1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(corVerde));
            img2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(corVerde));
            img3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(corVerde));
            img4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(corVerde));

            Intent intent = new Intent(Cores.this, MudaCor.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - please include the stacktrace, and code for both Activities, at a minimum, with your question.

Comment: btw, I would be interested to know who is `he` and `her` in your post.

Comment: Sorry, he is the Cores code. Her is the MudaCores activity.

Comment: public class MudaCor extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_muda_cor);

    }

}

Comment: I need to know how to change the background of a button from another activity.

Comment: You aren't changing anything in the other activity because that Intent is empty

Comment: Also, `img1` cannot be referenced across activities, so that's why your app is probably crashing